# Junk characters (smart quotes, etc.) in output file

Tags: python, mysql, vim, encoding, smart-quotes

I am reading a bunch of strings from mysql database using python, and after some processing, writing them to a CSV file. However I see some totally junk characters appearing in the csv file. For example when I open the csv using gvim, I see characters like `<92>`,`<89>`, `<94>` etc.

Any thoughts? I tried doing string.encode('utf-8') before writing to csv but that gave an error that `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 905: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the code just yet. I can post some pseudocde if you really need. It is just simple database read, and then concatenation of few strings, and then write to CSV.

Comment: What encoding are you receiving from the database?

Comment: @Amber, the default one? It is latin1_swedish_ci?

Comment: `<92>` is not a character (it’s four). Is that a *gvim* feature/representation?

Comment: @Kissaki - Well that's what I see in gvim. In gedit, it shows up as garbage.

Comment: @Kissaki It is the way Vim represents invalid characters.

Comment: @JayZee If you do `e ++enc=latin1` don’t these characters become meaningful? (And what does “_swedish_ci” mean in “It is latin1 _swedish_ci”?)

Comment: @ZyX : I did `gvim -c "e ++enc=latin1" data.csv` and no, I still see the same junk characters.

Comment: @ZyX : `latin1_swedish_ci`is what I gathered from the `collation` field of MySQL from under Phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it. I was using MySQLdb python module to connect to mysql. I just used `charset=utf8` and `use_unicode = True` while creating a database connection with it. Further, I changed the MySQL table's collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`. Finally when writing my string to csv file, I used:

```
file_pointer.write(my_string.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

I don't know how sound the logic is, but this is what I unearthed after several hours of googling, and it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`UnicodeDecodeError` means that you're trying to encode bytes i.e., Python 2 tries first to decode it to Unicode and then encode it using the specified encoding:

```
>>> b"€".encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

If the data is a text (not an inherently binary data such as image); you should work with it using Unicode. If your database driver doesn't return Unicode than convert the bytes to Unicode as soon as you receive them.

csv module on Python 2 only works with bytes. You could use `UnicodeWriter` from [the examples](http://docs.python.org/library/csv#examples) or similar to write Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Are all these "junk" characters in the range <80> to <9F>? If so, it's highly likely that they're Microsoft "Smart Quotes" (Windows-125x encodings). Someone wrote up the text in Word or Outlook, and copy/pasted it into a Web application. Both Latin-1 and UTF-8 regard these characters as control characters, and the usual effect is that the text display gets cut off (Latin-1) or you see a ?-in-black-diamond-invalid-character (UTF-8).

Note that Word and Outlook, and some other MS products, provide a UTF-8 version of the text for clipboard use. Instead of <80> to <9F> codes, Smart Quotes characters will be proper multibyte UTF-8 sequences. If your Web page is in UTF-8, you should normally get a proper UTF-8 character instead of the Smart Quote in Windows-125x encoding. Also note that this is not guaranteed behavior, but "seems to work pretty consistently". It all depends on a UTF-8 version of the text being available, and properly handled (i.e., you didn't paste into, say, gvim on the PC, and then copy/paste into a Web text form). This may well also work for various PC applications, so long as they are looking for UTF-8-encoded text.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix these in vim.  For example, to deal with <92> (which is single quote), do

```
:1,$s/CNTRL-V x 92/'/g
```

So you type CNTRL then V then x then 92 (no spaces).  You'll see it come out just like

```
:1,$s/<92>/'/g
```